# How can I sort by alphabetical order in Angular 11?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular11

It should be a simple task but, I am a new Angular user and I need to sort by alphabetic my object from API HTTP Get call.

This is my service that retrieves data from API:

```
getCustomer(key: string, page: number, pageSize: number): Observable<PagedResponse<Customer>> {
  return this.http
    .get<PagedResponse<Customer>>(environment.UrlApiSubscription + "Customer/" + key + "/" + page + "/" + pageSize, super.GetAuthTokenHeader())
    .pipe(
      map(super.extract),
      catchError(super.serviceError)
    )
}
```

And this is my base service:

```
protected extract(respose: any) {
    return respose || {};
}

protected serviceError(response: Response | any) {
    let customError: string[] = [];

    if (response instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
      if (response.statusText === "Unknown Error") {
        customError.push("Error");
        response.error.errors = customError;
      }
    }

    console.error(response);
    return throwError(response);
}
```

Comment: what is the reason of posting `base service` code

Comment: The "base service" Is the place where I am extracting the data. Maybe it is the place where I need to change. Just because of it. Ignore if does not make sense for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really not clear to me but I could suggest that to sort your response you can refer to below code, where attribute will be your property on the basis of which you want to sort your array result in alphabetical order

```
response.sort((a, b) => (a.attribute < b.attribute ) ? -1 : 1)
```